# How do I implement UIScrollView programatically

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview

I am launching detail pages from a UITableView and within that detail page there is an image. I would like it to be zoomable, so I'd like the contents of that detail page to sit inside a scrollView. So far no luck, the labels, textviews and images are fine, but I can't get the ScrollView implemented.

here is my .m:   THANKS!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

 UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
 scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 700);
 scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
 super.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 [scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];




 self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:selectedCellItem];



 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);

 self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];



 frame = CGRectMake(0, 320, 10, 10);



 UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

 //label.text = selectedCellItem;


 label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:20.0];
 label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

 [self.view addSubview:label];

 [label release];

 frame = CGRectMake(0, 320, 320, 60); //Description



 UITextView *labelDesc = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

 labelDesc.text = selectedCellDesc;
 labelDesc.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12.0];
 labelDesc.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

 //labelDesc.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentTop;

 [self.view addSubview:labelDesc];

 [labelDesc release];




 frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320); //Image

 UIImageView *imageItem = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
 [imageItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:selectedCellImage]];

 // GET THIS ONE WORKING RIGHT>>[imageItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath], selectedCellImage]]]; //use 

 //imageItem = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"shirt.png", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
 //labelDesc.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size:13.0];
 //labelDesc.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

 imageItem.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
 [self.view addSubview:imageItem];






 //[imageItem release];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}



/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're missing the following line to add the UIScrollView as a subview.

[self.view addSubView:scrollView];

Comment: If I put that line of code in line 5 (above "self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:selectedCellItem];" ) It actually causes a run-time crash (though it compiles fine) I really appreciate the help tho...any other ideas?

Comment: Can you share a call stack for the crash?

Comment: Happy to share one. Thanks so much!2010-11-13 18:02:44.953 KeepMe[65124:207] -[UIView addSubView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7329b30
2010-11-13 18:02:44.956 KeepMe[65124:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView addSubView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7329b30'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x025ed919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0273b5de

Comment: objc_exception_throw + 47
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x025ef42b -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x0255f116 ___forwarding___ + 966
 4   CoreFoundation                      0x0255ecd2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
 5   KeepMe                              0x00003f34 -[TableViewController viewDidLoad] + 336
 6   UIKit                               0x00377c26 -[UIViewController view] + 179
 7   UIKit                               0x00376050 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 42

Comment: 19  CoreFoundation                      0x025d0384 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1364
 20  CoreFoundation                      0x0252cd09 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
 21  CoreFoundation                      0x0252c280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
 22  CoreFoundation                      0x0252c1a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
 23  GraphicsServices                    0x02e522c8 GSEventRunModal + 217
 24  GraphicsServices                    0x02e5238d GSEventRun + 115
 25  UIKit                               0x002ddb58 UIApplicationMain + 1160
 26  KeepMe                              0x00002078 main +

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>


@interface TableViewController : UIViewController {
 
 NSString *selectedCellItem;
 NSString *selectedCellDesc;
 NSString *selectedCellImage;
 NSString *selectedCellLink;
 NSMutableArray *descList;
 NSMutableArray *itemsList;
 NSMutableArray *imageList;
 NSMutableArray *linkList;
 NSString *cellValue;
 UIImageView *imageItem;
 IBOutlet UILabel *desc;
 IBOutlet UIImageView *pic;

Comment: }

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedCellItem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedCellDesc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedCellImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedCellLink;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *cellValue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *itemsList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *descList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *imageList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *linkList;

Comment: @property(nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageItem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *desc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *pic;

Comment: Wait, I think I see it. You add it at line 5 but self.view hasn't been allocated yet. That's done 2 lines down.

Comment: I've tried it in a few other places, but doesn't seem to compile how specifically am I to allocate it?